# how to predict target label using scikit-learn.predict function for two classes?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a classifier that has two classes(`VALID` and `INVALID`).

My ground truth target values(`y_true`) are `y_true = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`

Estimated targets(`y_pred`) as returned by the classifier are `y_pred = [9.483586549758911133e-01, 7.377880215644836426e-01, 9.916032552719116211e-01, 2.021863758563995361e-01, 1.784837543964385986e-01]`

how to get this `y_pred` values as 0 or 1? I have used a cutoff 0.5 where if any value less than 0.5 treat as 0 and rest of 1. But It's showing a very less F1 score. Without using this cutoff when I used `classification_report(y_true, y_pred)`, it's showing almost perfect F1 score.

So, I am not getting how to get this target label`y_pred` values as 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y_pred = [9.483586549758911133e-01, 7.377880215644836426e-01, 9.916032552719116211e-01, 2.021863758563995361e-01, 1.784837543964385986e-01]
>>> np.where(np.array(y_pred) >= 0.5, 1, 0)
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: thank you for your response. But When I use `array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0])` to calculate the F1 score it will show less F1 score. and when I used `y_pred = [9.483586549758911133e-01, 7.377880215644836426e-01, 9.916032552719116211e-01, 2.021863758563995361e-01, 1.784837543964385986e-01]` it showing much high F1 score. So why this differences?

Comment: @SupriyaChanda F1 score is calculated based on the actual label and not on the probabilities. You should use the array of 0s and 1s for both predicted and actual values.